# How can I use onDraw on Fragment?

Tags: android, drawing

I have Fragment activity where I display contents using RelativeLayout. I am displaying text and everything is working OK.

Now I would like to add some graphics information and I have problems. There is no onDraw() method in Fragment.

Is there a way where I would be able to use RelativeLayout to display text information and draw at the same time on Fragment?

Thank you.

**Update:**

I am using this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{  
  mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stat, container, false);  
  return mFragmentView;  
}
```

From what I understand I will have to override (or change) the View that is created by Inflater.inflate() method. How can I do that?

Comment: I think building custom relative layout and overriding onDraw is a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing in a Fragment in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280685/drawing-in-a-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You just do not understand what the fragment. This is a common problem. Learn the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html).

The fragment is like a small part of the activity. It does not have a method of drawing. Drawing have View. You just need to add your View to a fragment.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23282354/2413972).